# Pull a column of data from one sheet to another based on a matching criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am new to Google sheet formula and need some help from the community.

I have two tabs from a spreadsheet, A and B:

- Both tabs basically have the same number of columns (col1, col2 and col3) except that col3 of B is all empty
- In terms of records, A is a subset of B. All the records in A should have matching records in B using col1 and col2.
- The orders of records in A and B are different which makes the matching more complicated

What I wanted to do is to pull col3 from A and to copy its values to corresponding records in B.

Here are visual examples:

```
         A
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  10  |  12  |  11  |
+------+------+------+
|  9   |  8   |  10  |
+------+------+------+

         B
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  10  |  12  |      | <-- this should have 11 from A
+------+------+------+
|  9   |  8   |      | <-- this should have 10 from A
+------+------+------+
|  9   |  7   |      | <-- this should be still empty since there is no matching record.
+------+------+------+
```

How can I do this by using google sheet formula?

I tried FILTER function and but I wasn't sure how to specify the matching criteria.

Comment: Why FILTER()? Why not SUMIFS()? Like as `=SUMIFS(<$source col3>,<$source col1>,<cell in B col1>,<$source col2>,<cell in B col2>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing what you want is to create a new column on your spreadsheet A, that would contain the combined columns A & B. You would move your original spreadsheets to column B-D and column A1 would be = A1&B1.

Then you can use a simple lookup on your spreadsheet B, that would look like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1&B1,A!A1:D10,4,false)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a simple task for:

```
=index(A!A1:A)
```

or did I not understand something?

**EDIT**

Following your comment, you can insert this formula in `B!C1`, which does not require the insertion of other columns in `A!` (nor in `B!`) and that will automatically fill in ALL cells of column `C` of `B!`:

```
=ifna(index(vlookup(B!A1:A&B!B1:B,{A!A1:A&A!B1:B,A!C1:C},2,false)))
```

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S1TFGUv2VI50l1j5D--BnareeeoUuBCKn2d7G-6zCp4/edit?usp=sharing) to test file

[image: lookup]

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention one more import thing. The orders of records in A and B are different :(

Comment: I have updated my answer